# [nav2] How to trigger the nav2 BT navigator from another node?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that the BT navigator starts going to work when a topic is being published to, but I want to feed the algorithm a pre-made path. If I call the FollowPath action server directly, will the BT navigator use the behavior tree to navigate? Otherwise, what's the proper way for an outside node to send a navigation mission to the nav2 system without asking the system to compute a path?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403879/%5Bnav2%5D-how-to-trigger-the-nav2-bt-navigator-from-another-node?/) by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2022-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create your own behavior tree with your custom application logic, bypassing the components you don't need and/or replacing them with custom BT nodes for what you want to do.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) on 2022-07-19**:
Yes, that seems like the solution. Feedback: Say I do. Then, to trigger ticking the root of the BT, I call the `navigate_to_pose` action client with an empty goal, after which it will tick the root and can proceed loading behaviors I need. It would be nice to trigger the tick without going for an empty action goal on an action server called navigate_to_pose, when my BT is not exactly about navigating to pose.